# Slice an array with spaces in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to use a key-value storage in bash, and then access the elements and work with them. I have the following code so far, which finds the key in the storage, but can't extract the values from the array without interpreting the spaces.

A straight forward solution to this (since I know there will be three values for each key) is to access those directly, but surely there must be a way to slice the array properly.

```
# the array is a key: value storage, the keys do not contain spaces, but the values might
# there are always three values for each key, but the number of words in them is unknown
services=("key1" "some values" "another_value" "a lot of values"
          "key2" "other values" "simple_value2" "a lot of values here"
          "key3" "something else here" "another_value3" "whatever")

# this should look for the given value in the array and return the key and respective values if its found
function find_key () {
    arr=("${@:2}")
    len=$(( ${#arr[@]} -1 ))
    for i in $(seq 0 4 "$len")
    do
    if [[ ${arr[$i]} == "$1" ]] ; then
        # this should get the i'th element and 4 following elements (the values), which works correctly
        result="${arr[*]:$i:4}"
        # at this point result is just a regular array and there is no way to separate the values again

        # this prints just one line with all words
        for x in "${result[@]}"; do
            echo "element: '$x'"
        done

        # I want to return the array ("key" "value 1" "value 2" "the third value") from here to work with it later
        echo "${result[@]}"
        return 0
    fi
    done
    return 1
}

key_and_values="$(find_key "key2" "${services[@]}")"
echo "${key_and_values[@]}"
```

The output is:

```
element: 'key2 other values simple_value2 a lot of values here'
key2 other values simple_value2 a lot of values here
```

And I am looking for:

```
element: 'key2'
element: 'other values'
element: 'simple_value2'
element: 'a lot of values here'
key2 other values simple_value2 a lot of values here
```

Comment: `"${key_and_values[@]}"` `key_and_values` is not an array

Comment: No, it is not. The problem is at the line `result="${arr[*]:$i:4}"`, where it changes from array to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
result="${arr[*]:$i:4}"
```

into an array:

```
result=("${arr[@]:$i:4}")
```

There are some problems with your script:

- `"${key_and_values[@]}"` - `key_and_values` is not an array, it's a normal variable.
- `echo "${result[@]}"` will work abnormally when for example `result[0]='-n'`. Use `printf "%s\n" "${result[@]}" | paste -sd ' '` or similar.

I think I would go with something along:

```
find_key() {
    arr=("${@:2}")
    for ((i=0; i < ${#arr[@]}; i+=4)); do
        if [[ ${arr[$i]} == "$1" ]] ; then
            printf "%s\0" "${arr[@]:$i:4}"
            return 0
        fi
    done
    return 1
}

readarray -d '' -t key_and_values < <(find_key "key2" "${services[@]}")
printf "element: %s\n" "${key_and_values[@]}"
printf "%s\n" "${key_and_values[@]}" | paste -sd' '
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this tehniq in [piu-piu](https://github.com/vaniacer/piu-piu-SH)

```
array=("abs 123 ---" "DEF 456 +++")
for items in "${array[@]}"; {
    sub=( $items )
    echo  ======
    for item in ${sub[@]}; {
        echo $item
    }
}
```

output

```
======
abs
123
---
======
DEF
456
+++
```

Also you can use an associative array and loop over indexes

```
declare -A items=( [item1]="123 abc" [item2]="dfe 234" )

for key in ${!items[@]}; {
    echo "key=$key"
    echo "val=${items[$key]}"
}
```

output

```
key=item2
val=dfe 234
key=item1
val=123 abc
```

But the question was about slicing right?), of course you can slice an array like this

```
array=("abs 123" "DEF 456" "ASA 789")

$ echo "${array[@]:1}"
DEF 456 ASA 789

$ echo "${array[@]::1}"
abs 123

$ echo "${array[@]:1:3}"
DEF 456 ASA 789

$ echo "${array[@]:1:1}"
DEF 456
```